# Bhuvaneswari Yantra - which is the correct version?

Tags: dasha-mahavidya

In Rudrayamala Tantram, bhuvaneswari yantra is described like below.
[image]

In another famous book on mahavidyas -

> The Ten Great Cosmic powers, by S Sankaranarayan

, the yantra is depicted as below, 8 petals in the outer ring instead of 16 as mentioned in Rudryamal.
[image]

Am I misinterpreting the text? Or is one of them incorrect? and which one?

Comment: IMO The picture represents the incorrect one as षोड़शः means 16, Everything else matches the description though....

Comment: @Rickross Ji your opinion here would be really valuable 

Comment: exactly, trying to confirm if its 8 or 16. the rest matches

Answer (score 0):

I recently read the book called "`Yantras Heavenly Geometries`" by `Govinda Das Aghori (https://www.aghori.it/govinda_das_eng.htm)`

The description in Rudrayamala matches the yantra mentioned in this book.
So I am going to answer my own question stating that Rudrayamala description is the correct one.